# How can I install TLP in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, tlp

I tried installing TLP in ubuntu 18.04 using the command line

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Actually the PPA you added has no software for your Ubuntu release. As the comment above suggests, install it normally AND remove all those old PPAs you've been adding.

Comment: I just installed ubuntu few days back and I am complete beginner. so how do I install the correct PPA ?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia so should I uncheck the boxes for all the PPAs from software and updates?

Comment: You don't install any PPA for TLP. TLP is available at the official repositories and can be installed like anything else you find in Ubuntu Sofware. And, yes, you should definitely remove all those PPAs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are reading old instructions off the internet. `tlp` is included in Ubuntu's universe repository so all you need to type is:

```
sudo apt install tlp
```

If you want to utilize the Radio Wizard also use:

```
sudo apt install tlp-rdw
```

Thinkpad users can install optional packages for battery threshold levels:

```
sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
```

Source: [Welcome to TLP!](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. How effective is TLP in extending battery life?

Comment: @Rima I run my laptops plugged in 24/7 but I've heard others say how it extends from 4 hours to 10 hours after all power saving features are enabled, not just in `tlp` but also in gnome / unity where screen is dimmed after 10 seconds of inactivity, etc.

Comment: @Rima: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. You’re welcome to send me a comment with a notification to draw my attention to it. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks but my problem has been solved now. :)

Comment: According to TLP's documentation, the Thinkpad packages are optional for more control.

Comment: @Alex Thank you. I've changed it to "optional".

Comment: excuse me .. i followed this commands .. Does anything i should do it after that ? and is that way making battery in save without using it during plugin the charger ?

Answer (score 2):

For a person who is more into the UI, do the following.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tlpui
```

[image: ui]