# Why does my dual boot have a battery life of 11 hrs on Microsoft and only 2 hrs on Ubuntu?

Tags: 18.04

I have a Dell G3( 1 TB HDD + 256 GB SSD ) dual boot.
It continues to show its normal battery life on 11 hrs on Microsoft, while it shows a battery life of 2 - 2.5 hrs on Ubuntu, although Microsoft is much more sophisticated than Ubuntu. Somebody please tell me what to do( I am a student and I need a long battery life to code without constraint)

Comment: First step would be to install `tlp`:https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091959/how-can-i-install-tlp-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-batterywindows.html.en).