# Battery drain on suspend - Ubuntu 20.04 - ThinkPad T480

Tags: suspend, 20.04, battery, thinkpad

I have a ThinkPad T480 that I have been running linux on since day 1, approximately 1 year now. I also had the same problem with a previous laptop (ThinkPad T460).

In short, everything seems to suspend okay. I can close the lid, after a few moments the outside light on the lid starts pulsating, indicating suspend state.

However, when in suspend, there is what I would consider a higher than normal drain on the battery. For example, I had the laptop plugged in and suspended yesterday, and I unplugged it but kept it in suspend mode. 15-18 hours later, I opened it up again to see it had drained to 85%, so it's draining about 1%/hour.

I have TLP and powertop installed and set to defaults. I've found other people with this problem online but no solution that's been offered to them has worked for me.

Has anyone had the same problem, or knows of ways to troubleshoot?

edit: here is the contents of `/proc/acpi/wakeup`

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GLAN      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.6
XHC   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
XDCI      S4    *disabled
HDAS      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1f.3
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP09      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP10      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP11      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.2
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:3d:00.0
RP12      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP13      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP14      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP15      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP16      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP17      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP18      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP19      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP20      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP21      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP22      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP23      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP24      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I think it's because a bug in the recent version of the kernel(btw I use v5.4) . The standard state for suspend is G1S3 which means suspend to ram (a.k.a [STR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode)) .In this state the only device that has full electrical current is the RAM.Even most of the parts of the CPU is completely idle.So no program should get executed , but I noticed that that some programs like Telegram still runs in the background when I suspend my system.It can cause trouble if you left your laptop unplugged.

Comment: Can you please append the contents of the file **/proc/acpi/wakeup** to your post ?

Comment: Sure, I added it to the post

Comment: I was looking at a [bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192591) concerning the suspend/resume issue and in that case one of the devices of the OP had [**S0** as the S-state](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=251771) which means the normal state not low-power states.But looks like that's not the case here.

Comment: There a lot of ways to debug the suspending procedure.You can do a synchronous suspend (i.e suspending the devices in succession not parallel) by disabling the **pm_async** feature : `echo 0 > /sys/power/pm_async`. If the problem gets solved , it might be a device dependency problem.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll give it a shot and see what happens

Comment: From this answer: [How can I install TLP in Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091959/how-can-i-install-tlp-in-ubuntu-18-04/1091962#1091962) Thinkpad owners can install extra `tlp` programs designed just for them: `sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms`

Comment: 1% / h is pretty normal. Bear in mind that the RAM must continue to be supplied with power.

Comment: @linrunner that's reassuring, I guess the only point of comparison I have is using Windows which uses a form of hybrid sleep, and is thus more power-efficient. If this drain seems normal for typical suspend-to-RAM then I don't think there's a problem here